# What are typical size/values for Camera Matrix and Distortion Coefficients for camera calibration in opencv 3.0

Tags: c++, opencv, camera, calibration

When trying to use StereoCalibrate, StereoRectify, and initUndistortRectifyMap in opencv 3.0, I get runtime errors that reference size, and is labeled "Assertion failed".

I believe this must be due to my Camera Matrix and Distortion Coefficients. The outputed sizes for these were as follows:

*

```
CamMatrx: [3x3]
DistrtCoeff: [1x5]
ImgPoints: [54x15]
```

*

And these values are coming from a set of [659x494] calibration images. Something must be wrong.

Any ideas?

Thanks, 
Rowan

Comment: I got initUndistortRectifyMap() working in an isolated run. I'm also realizing that this question might be a bit too vague for anyone to give specific help.

Comment: Specifically, I get an Assertion failed error for the stereoCalibrate() method that reads: Assertion failed <nimages . 0 && nimages == <int.imagePoints1.total<> &&............in cv::collectCalibrationData.